# Having trouble understanding classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

i feel like this is a very simple concept but i just cant seem to wrap my head around classes and returning values from them... this what i've come up with to try and practice, very much WIP but i'm stuck here. 
thanks in advance

```
import random
global d6

print("welcome to fight night")

#dice roll
class die():
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        chance = random.randint(1,self.sides)
        if chance == 3:
         return True
    if chance != 3:
         return False
d6 = die(6)

class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, weight, spec):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.spec = spec


fighter1 = Player("BRUCE LEE", 150, "SUPER SPEED")
fighter2 = Player(GEORGE FORMAN", 225, "REACH")


## how do i return true or false here to check hit?
print(fighter1(name) + "attacks"+ fighter2(name))
d6.roll()
if d6 == True:
    print(fighter(name) + "hit" + fighter2(name))
if d6 == False:
    print("attack missed")
```

Comment: please be more specific. what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

A few things about class conventions:

- The name of a class should typically start with an uppercase letter.
- The `()` after the name of the class is not necessary unless you're
  using inheritance.

Code:

```
class Die:

    def __init__(self, number_of_sides):
        self.number_of_sides = number_of_sides

    def roll(self):
        """
        Returns True if the roll succeeds, returns False otherwise.
        There is a (1 / self.number_of_sides) chance the roll will succeed.
        """
        from random import choice
        return choice([True] + [False] * (self.number_of_sides-1))

die = Die(6)

if die.roll():
    print("Nice!")
else:
    print("Sorry, try again.")
```

**EDIT** I think you need a more fundamental example of how the `return` keyword works:

```
def give_me_a_number():
    return 5 + 4

x = give_me_a_number()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
9
```

Answer (score 0):

`d6.roll()` returns a value (which is `True` or `False`) -- `d6` does not **become** that value, it returns it to you.  When you roll a 3 on a real d6, the die does not itself entirely transform into the number 3 in a puff of smoke and mathemagicks, it just shows it to you on one of its faces.  :)

So you could do:

```
if d6.roll():
    print(fighter1.name + " hit " fighter2.name)
else:
    print("attack missed")
```

Or if you wanted to be more verbose:

```
die_result = d6.roll()
if die_result is True:
    print(fighter1.name + " hit " fighter2.name)
if die_result is False:
    print("attack missed")
```

Comment: so after d6 goes though the def roll(), it then holds the True or False... or i need to call d6.roll() as a True or False with my outcomes? btw thanks for the quick reply

Comment: It doesn't "hold" the value, it `return`s it.  When you do `die_result = d6.roll()` the `True` or `False` value is assigned to the `die_result` variable.  If you only want to do one thing with it (like use it as the predicate of an `if` statement), you don't need to assign it to a variable, you can just use it directly in place (like my first example does).

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure your die class such that it only returns a random value as the result of roll.  You generally want objects (instances of classes) to be independent - the user of the die object should determine what is done with the random value the object generates, not the die itself.

For example, let's say we have many players, of varying strengths. A strong player attacking a weak player should have odds different from a weak player attacking a strong player.  This data (strong vs weak) should be inside the player object, not the die object. So I'd make two more methods for the Player, and an attribute like 'strength' which gets an int value...

```
import random

class Die:
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        chance = random.randint(1,self.sides)
        return chance

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, weight, spec):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.spec = spec

    def get_stats(self):
        return self.spec

    def attack(self, target):
        odds = self.spec / (self.spec + target.get_stats())
        #print(odds)
        d6 = Die(6);
        temp = d6.roll()
        #print(temp)

        if (d6.roll() / 6 < odds):
            return ("hit")
        else:
            return ("miss")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("welcome to fight night")
    fighter1 = Player("BRUCE LEE", 150, 100)
    fighter2 = Player("GEORGE FORMAN", 225, 100)
    for x in range(20):
        result = fighter1.attack(fighter2)
        print(result)
```

So, now the Player objects control the odds themselves, not the die objects, making everything more flexible. (Making the Die a local object inside the function is a bit high on overhead, incidentally, but global objects/variables have many issues and are probably best avoided)